# Filter ArrayLists that just have intersected data

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have the following classes:

```
public class School{
    List<ClassRoom> classRooms;
}

public class ClassRoom{
    List<Student> students;
}

public class Student{
    String name;
    List<Long> typeIdList;
}
```

I need to get just the `typeId` that are a common factor among all students within the given class roomS.

To be able to get all students within the given class roomS that has typeID=123, I do the following:

```
final long typeIdToSearchFor = ...;
Collection<Student> filtered = Collections2.filter(students,
    new Predicate<Student>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Student s) {
            return s.typeId == typeIdToSearchFor;
        }
    }
);
```

Just wondering if Guava can handle something like that?
By intersection I mean that it MUST occur at all instance to consider this type.

I know that a `for` loop will be more readable but I just discover Guava capabilities.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're asking for.  Are you trying to check that all students in a collection have the same `typeId`?  A specific `typeId`?  What you have is already a Guava solution for getting all `Student`s that have a specified `typeId`.

Comment: What is this `Predicate` ? Guava or Apache Commons?

Comment: @Mark:I just need to get typID(s) that are common between all students

Comment: @Echo: I don't understand how two different `typeId`s could be common to all Students, when each student can only have one `typeId`.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Echo I have to agree here with Mark. Can you provide an example may be of what you want to achieve?

Comment: typeId can be repeated among students

Comment: @Echo so you want to get the unique typeId from a List of students?

Comment: @Echo: Right, but each Student can only have one `typeId`.  So how could there possibly be two `typeId`s which all students contain?

Comment: sorry my mistake .. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) which can count occurrences:

```
ClassRoom classRoom = /* comes from somewhere */;
List<Student> students = classRoom.getStudents();

// Aggregate all the typeIds.
Multiset<Long> typeIds = HashMultiset.create();
for (Student student : students) {
    // Assuming a student doesn't have duplicated typeIds:
    typeIds.addAll(student.getTypeIds());
}

// Find which typeIds are present for all the students.
for (Multiset.Entry<Long> entry : typeIds.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getCount() == students.size()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getElement());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check that all `Student`s have a specific `typeId`, use `Iterables.all` with your existing predicate.

You can also create a `Multimap` of `Student`s indexed by their `typeId` using `Multimaps.index()`:

```
Multimap<Long, Student> studentsByTypeId = Multimaps.index(students, new Function<Student, Long>() {
  public Long apply(Student s) {
    return s.typeId;
  }
};
```

Then you can get the unique `typeId`s using `studentsByTypeId.keySet()`.

You can check if they all share the same `typeId` using `studentsByTypeId.keySet().size() == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the ones that intersect you shouldn't compare to a specific one you should at least check if it's contained in the ids of the other collection. Like this:

```
new Predicate<Student>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Student s) {
        return otherIds.contains(s.typeId);
    }
}
```

But I still think that if you performed binary searches on both collections (after ordering them), you could get your answer so much faster. Something like this

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);

List<E> intersected = new ArrayList<E>();

for(E element : list1){
    if(Collections.binarySearch(list2, element) >= 0){
        intersected.add(element);
    }
}
```

You could even have a way to fin the smallest list. It could help it gain a bit of performance.

Comment: You solution is nice but in case I have dynamic number of lists ,it would need a some effort.

Comment: It is still doable. and if you have a dynamic number of lists, I strongly suggest you to think of a performatic way to do this, I'll try and edit my answer for a solution that englobes multiple collections. You want intersections among all of them?